# Проверка наличия символа в строке

Tags: php

Нужно проверить наличие символа в цифры в строке, и если ее нет вернуть строку с этой цифрой, если есть вернуть строку без нее. Использую функцию:

```
$str = '1,2,3';
    function get_str($str, $check) {
        $pos = strpos($check, $str); 
        if ($pos === false) {
            return $str . ',' . $check;
        } else {
            return $str;
        }
    }

    echo get_str($str, 1);
    echo get_str($str, 4);
```

Но она работает неправильно. Подскажите как можно реализовать задуманное.

Приведенный код возвращает:

```
1,2,3,1
1,2,3,4
```

Нужно:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: И в чем именно заключается "не правильность" работы функции? Приведите конкретные примеры входных/выходных данных и ваши ожидания.

Comment: 1,2,3,1 1,2,3,4 - вот что получается

Comment: аргументы strpos надо наоборот

Comment: @t16bz, а что должно получаться? Пожалуйста, добавьте эти примеры в вопрос в формате входные данные -- ожидаемый результат -- выходные данные.

Comment: Возьмите числа в кавычки

Comment: @t16bz, смотрите на комментарий _splash58_. Вы перепутали местами аргументы `strpos`

Comment: Добавил кавычки и поменял местами. Все работает! Всем спасибо!

Comment: «если есть вернуть строку без нее» – я понял, как «надо удалить из строки эту цифру»..

Comment: вообще-то, для меня открытие, `strpos('1,2',1)` выдает ложь, а не ноль

Comment: @splash58, почитайте [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php): _Если needle не является строкой, он приводится к целому и трактуется как код символа._

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev  о пользе чтения документации :)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых аргументы в [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) надо поменять местами.

Во-вторых в strpos надо передавать строку, так что или оберните цифры в кавычки или в самой функции преобразуйте в строку.

```
$str = '1,2,3';
function get_str($str, $check) {
    $pos = strpos($str, (string)$check);
    if ($pos === false) {
        return $str . ',' . $check;
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}

echo get_str($str, 1);
echo get_str($str, 4);
```

возвращает:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
```

Но вообще удобнее будет преобразовывать все в массив и с ним работать:

```
$str = '1,2,3';
function get_str($str, $check) {
    $arr = explode(',' , $str); // преобразовать строку в массив
    $pos = array_search($check, $arr); //ищем элемент в массиве
    if ($pos === false) {
        $arr[] = $check; // добавляем
        return implode(',', $arr); //возвращаем строку
    } else {
        unset($arr[$pos]); //удаляем (я как понял, если есть то надо удалить)
        return implode(',', $arr); //возвращаем строку
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Неплохо и с регуляркой (проверяем, что $check - цифра, которой нет в $str):

```
$str = '1,2,3';

function get_str($str, $check) {
    if(preg_match("/^\d$/", $check) && (preg_match("/$check/", $str)==0)){
        return "$str,$check";
    }
    return $str;
}   

echo get_str($str, "fake")."<br>";
echo get_str($str, 1)."<br>";
echo get_str($str, 4);
```

Результаты:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
```